# discord ASCII bot python characters aren't all the same length so it looks bad

Tags: python, discord, ascii-art

So made a simple discord bot that gives the user a banner command
'
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
print('Dictbot running smooth')

```
@commands.command()
async def banner(self, ctx, *, msg):
    ascii_banner = self.cus_fig.renderText(msg) 
    discord_banner = ''
    for charecter in ascii_banner:
        discord_banner += charecter
        if (charecter == ' '):
            discord_banner += '  '
        
    print(ascii_banner)
    await ctx.send(discord_banner)

@commands.command()
async def font(self, ctx, *, fontName):
    self.cus_fig = Figlet(font=fontName)
```

I used pyfiglet which works just find when i print the art to terminal but in discord not all the characters are the same width so it looks super ugly. I did a temporary fix by making all of the single spaces become 3 spaces which works OK but the letters are slightly off. And I can only use the banner3 font which is only pounds and spaces. is their any way to make all the characters the same distance apart in discord? Or a better way to do what im doing

Answer (score 2):

I just have the same problem.
It seems that put the text in a code block (with ``` at the beginning and the end) fix the width of each character.
You can also try to replace space with that "⠀" character.

Comment: When you'll get 50 reputation, remember to use comments for such tips.